# FileDescriptor.in v/s System.in

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

In Java, we can use Scanner class for taking input but it is not as efficient as BufferedReader of IO Package.
While Initializing the Scanner class's object or BufferedReader class's object we use InputStream "System.in".
Is System.in is good as compared to FileDescriptor.in?

Like if I use System.in with BufferedReader:

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

And using FileDescriptor.in:

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in), "ASCII"));`

Same goes while printing:

Using System.out OutputStream:

`System.out.println("Hello World!");`

Using FileDescriptor.out with BufferedWriter:

`BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out),"ASCII"), 512);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your question is **"Is `System.in` good as compared to `FileDescriptor.in`?"**

Answers:

1. They're **different**. `System.in` can be changed with `System.setIn` but `FileDescriptor.in` always points to the same IO source (while you're running the program, unless you use native code), so you're less flexible if you use `FileDescriptor.in`.
2. With the default settings when the VM starts, the performance is the same, if you keep in mind the `System.in` is buffered, so any alternative needs to be buffered too.

The proof of point 2 is in the source code in the `System` class:

```
    FileInputStream fdIn = new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in);
    // ...
    setIn0(new BufferedInputStream(fdIn));
```

The standard stream that you get from `System.in` is a `FileInputStream` that reads from `FileDescriptor.in`, but there is a `BufferedInputStream` wrapped around it for performance reasons (it improves the performance of small reads).